Logical monitoring of program sequence
Following ISO/IEC 61508 functional safety standard (or ISO 26262), logical monitoring of program sequence is a suggested diagnostic method, to verify an application following the intended path.
However, I can't (easily?) find any in-depth analysis of the method, and no source code reference at all, addressing this technique. The only document easy to retrieve on the subject is AUTOSAR documentation, although it doesn't look to me very practical, raising more questions than giving answers.
Many other references are again just articles that claim how good is functional safety standardization, without any additional reference to books or detailed analysis.
Does anybody have any reference to practical/analytical approaches to runtime program sequence monitoring?

There are tools that will instrument your code to verify code coverage, then you apply unit test techniques to exercise the code.  Other tools such as PolySpace can statically analyse your code using "abstract execution" to check for potential or definite runtime errors.  Many MCUs have on-chip debug that include trace capability, but you need the appropriate pins and closed in the hardware, a trace capable debug interface, and debugger software thatt can process and present that data.  So the answer is you apply tooling to the problem.

Note that all the static analysis methods, such as dynamic analysis by unit testing, are required and described separately by the standard. The program sequence monitoring isn't covered by the former ones. The cited AUTOSAR paper describes it as another kind of dynamic analysis, following the flow graph of the code at runtime.

@Clifford Static/dynamic code coverage is a separate requirement in 61508 iirc. And as I understand it, "logical monitoring" refers to monitoring the program counter, so it is closer to the metal and partially hardware-related. Code coverage being a pure software behavior check.

@Lundin understood, but as a "suggested" method, you might omit it if you could perhaps demonstrate other methods achieving similar quality control.  Moreover the OP describes it as a diagnostic technique, suggesting it's use in fault finding rather than test/validation. How is that then different than use of ICE/OCD with trace capability I wonder?

@Clifford note also that this is a requirement for an online test, processed during runtime, not in a debug environment.

@Clifford Fault diagnostic in the context of safety-related products/software refers to the product's own ability to spot faulty behavior. "Diagnostic coverage" is a big term in functional safety meaning the probability to spot one particular error.

@LuC it has changed from a suggestion to a requirement in your last comment.

@Clifford in 61508-3 table A.2 group 3, there's a list of alternative or equivalent measures to adopt; program sequence monitoring is among the ones suggested to achieve a requirement. Unfortunately, in English, I can't express myself as well as in my mother tongue

@LuC understood.

A good article on what AUTOSAR describes as logical supervision (akin to the logical monitoring original theme) is the one published as Software Architecture Modeling of AUTOSAR-Based Multi-Core Mixed-Critical Electric Powertrain Controller.
Even though it doesn't answer directly my original question, it details very succinctly in a straightforward description of how such a supervising feature works. In section 3.2 there is a simple and clear description of how the software watchdog manager functions, as an analyzer of the program flow graph created by the part of a process supervised (supervised entity), by using a sequence of checkpoints placed in the key points of execution.
As that is an open-access document, nicely written, I think it is well worth mentioning.
[EDIT]
Lately, I have been directed to an application note from STM AN4435, that describes a few measures to take with their microcontrollers to fulfill a few safety standards.
In paragraph 5.1.3 of the above, they approach the "Flow control procedure", which has been very much employed for program sequence monitoring.
Warning: In Figure 3 of that document there are a couple of mistaken variable names! The four variable assignments in the sequence shall be read as
Counter = Counter + 5
...
Counter = Counter + 7
...
Counter_ = Counter_ - 7
...
Counter_ = Counter_ - 5

(Variable naming isn't the best ability of the writer...)

Some parts of these standards you just have to argument back at. WTH is "logical monitoring" would be a highly justified question to ask. IEC 61508-7 provides explanations, but in this case calling the explanation and rationale bleak would be an understatement:

Logical monitoring of program sequence
Aim: To monitor the correct sequence of the individual program sections.
Description: The correct sequence of the individual program sections is monitored using software (counting procedure, key procedure) or using external monitoring facilities. it is important that the checking points are placed in the program correctly.
Reference: Microcomputers in safety technique - an aid to orientation for developer and manufacturer. H.Hölscher, J.Rader, Verlag TÜV Rheinland, Köln, 1986, ISBN 3-88585-315-9

Sigh. Ok I'm not going to rob some technical museum just to get my hands on this book and claim 61508 conformance and I very much doubt that some dusty old tome from 1986 has a lot of relevance to teach me anyway. It's from the dark ages where parallel buses as an extension to the MCU address bus was common, as well as external ROM where the program was stored.
At this point it is seriously justified to start a FMEA of IEC 61508 itself:
Risk: The standard uses a single source for its claim and that one source is horrendously outdated. It is not based on scientific methods or modern engineering best practices.
Hazard: very high.
I suppose what they are trying to communicate is that some sort of program counter monitoring would be nice, or otherwise that the program is executed in sequence.
In modern times I suppose this is about poking the MCU vendor of your safety MCU and ask how they monitor the program counter, apart from the obvious watch dog features. Most likely using a safety MCU with lock-step cores is an acceptable solution to this, since their program counters must follow.
On the higher application level, we might of course also implement some manner of defensive programming. We can implement the whole program as a number of states and allow transition of states from a single point in the program only - this is common practice. That also means that we can restrict the state variable to a single translation unit (in terms of C programming) and that no other parts of the program has access to it. We ensure integrity by not handing out access to that state variable left and right.

At some point they should have found how old and unaccessible was the reference, then with 61508-7:2010 had been removed: without any further clarification...

By the way, in my case 'lockstep' doesn't apply, as the safe CPU is single-core, non-duplicated - yet certifiable up to SIL3. I will take into consideration the advice on restricting state change modification. However, the original text keeps being a puzzle...

@LuC I really think lock-step ought to be the appropriate, modern safety measure in this case and you ought to be able to claim as much. You can't get much better PC monitoring than that, since each core ought to have its own PC. If you aren't using a lock-step MCU then it will be much harder to justify it. Which MCU are you using, if I may ask?

@LuC The original source probably suggested something much more rudimentary and crude monitoring from the 1980s. I mean on-chip watchdogs wasn't even standard back then, and on-chip LVD didn't become standard until 2005 somewhere. There's been like 5 or so generations of MCUs since the 1980s.

the device will be a TI DSP in the families F28003x/F28004x, then a single core - even though it almost has a second specialized CPU unit (dubbed CLA), with another architecture, which can add some code diversity and parallel processing. I can't then process 'in parallel', but reasonably can verify some behavior in a second environment. I just would like to know more about the standard's definition, as it is viable with a single CPU, with code separation

@LuC I'm honestly not sure how to supervise the PC meaningfully otherwise, because it can obviously not be done from software. Iirc TI has lock-step safety MCUs but maybe not in the DSP flavour?

that's one of my doubts as well, on what the standard says Diverse monitor techniques (with independence between the monitor and the monitored function in the same computer). I can only translate it to two different tasks, on the same CPU :shrug:

@LuC That's easier though, it probably means having 2 different technologies overlapping the same safety function, for example if you have a 24V emergency stop line bus also a separate CAN bus in parallel where the stop information is also transmitted. Or if you have a inductive sensor and an optical sensor both for the same input function, etc etc.

@LuC And there's the separate matter of "redundancy", which is common best practice in safety-critical systems. For example you could have 2 MCUs supervising two actuators and each of them might make the decision to stop, so that a single failure will not break the safety function. This could arguably be implemented with multiple cores in the same IC, but maybe not for the highest SILs.
